# VBA VLOOKUP Formula Compile error

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I always have a Compile error: 
Expected: end of statemets
And always show me ths part of code **("F1:H66")**

```
Public Sub macro2()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Range("G31").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-4],Sheet2.Range("F1:H66"),3, False)"
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The error is actually quite easy to see here on SO, look at the text color on the formula. It's red between the " ", and black on the range and then red again. In most IDE (maybe all) a color change of the text is something you should look at closely. It may be correct, but most of the times a color change is bad. In VBA editor there is no such luxury unfortunately, but SO  has it.

Comment: Thank you ... Thats why i ask where is the problem because i'm not experienced one in VBA and i see that VBA editor have change color only in keywords. Notepad++ can solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Chr(34)` to have the `"`, it's easier to read.

Second, try to avoid using `Select` and `ActiveCell`, instead you can use the direct Range approach, see code below :

```
Range("G31").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-4],Sheet2.Range(" & Chr(34) & "F1:H66" & Chr(34) & "),3, False)"
```

Answer (score 2):

double-up your double-quotes when they occur inside a string:

`"=VLOOKUP(RC[-4],Sheet2.Range(""F1:H66""),3, False)"`

`------------------------------^--------^----------`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code. You can adjust the cells values as you wish.

```
NewValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( Range("G31"), Range("F1:H66"), 3, False )
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use
`"=VLOOKUP(RC[-4],Sheet2!R1C6:R66C8,3, False)"`

This will give the formula:  `=VLOOKUP(C31,Sheet2!$F$1:$H$66,3, FALSE)`